# Bootstrap select doesn't return clickedIndex on changed.bs.select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using [Bootstrap Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) plugin.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="veicoli" data-style="btn-transparent" data-title="Veicoli" data-selected-text-format="static" data-live-search="true" multiple>
        <option value="1">EA018YE</option>
        <option value="11">FM088KP</option>
        <option value="17">DT590LW</option>
        <option value="21">DB814RZ</option>
        <option value="33">DM408DG</option>
        <option value="40">EH942GJ</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I select options programatically using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#veicoli').selectpicker('val', data);
  $('#veicoli').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

where `data` is an array:

```
["11", "33"]
```

The code above correctly select options in the bootstrap-select, but the fired event `changed.bs.select`, that I defined like this:

```
$(document).on('changed.bs.select', '#modale-dettagli #veicoli', function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
  console.log('e: ' + e);
  console.log('clickedIndex: ' + clickedIndex);
  console.log('isSelected: ' + isSelected);
  console.log('previousValue: ' + previousValue);
}
```

doesn't work as expected because `clickedIndex` is `undefined`

This is the output of the event above:

```
e: [object Object]
clickedIndex: undefined
isSelected: undefined
previousValue: undefined
```

Note that when the same options are clicked (with the mouse), the same event works correctly

**EDIT:** Just so you understand, the problem I'm experiencing now was a bug in an earlier version [val() method doesn't fire changed.bs.select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1303)

**EDIT 2:** I've found that I can get the index of the selected option with `this.selectedIndex` (instead of using function parameter `clickedIndex`) and with some "code trick" the job can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clickedIndex` is purposely only returned when a click event has been fired (when manually selecting an option). The documentation should probably be updated to reflect this, but it would be difficult to implement properly when using the `val()` method, as in the case of a multiple select, multiple values can be changed at once (so it would be difficult to determine which elements would be considered "clicked"). However, `previousValue` *should* be returned, and the fact that it isn't is a bug. That will be fixed in bootstrap-select v1.13.9, though (https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2244).